# How to Redirect view based on Condition in angular $routeProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

i am working on angularjs and using below code

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/Home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/About'
    })
```

Here, how can I put condition that 
if file "help.html" is exist on project deployed folder like(D:\project\Code\help.cshtml)then page should redirect or we can say it should open help page"help.cshtml.

if not then my normal route should work.
please suggest for best approach.

Comment: For which route you want to display `help.html`? You can't open `cshtml` file directly, there is routing mechanism for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept route errors by listening for `$routeChangeError` events.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
  }).when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile.html'
  }).when('/help', {
    // The help.html does not exist
    templateUrl: 'help.html', 
    // Set a custom property we'll use to redirect to if needed
    redirectOnError: '/help-not-found' 
  }).when('/help-not-found', {
    templateUrl: 'help-not-found.html'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

  // Listen for route errors

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current) {

    // And if the route contains our custom property ...

    if(current.$$route.redirectOnError) {

      console.log('Redirecting to ' + current.$$route.redirectOnError);

      // Redirect to that route

      $location.path(current.$$route.redirectOnError);
    }
  });

});
```

See it in action in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWjKck2vRZwIrmQiWwVG?p=preview).

Comment: i am using angular-1-1-5.min.js.so in case i can't use ngRoute.

Comment: Which routing module is providing the `$routeProvider` from your example?